# How can I change the precision of a grafana query to influxdb?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I know I can change the precision in influxdb once I am conected to it using cli. Or in a query in ajax : api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=telegraf&q=show+tag+values+with+key=topic&precision=s

But I want to do it in a grafana query because I want to render a panel with another precision. Any help?

Thank you